# Tooltip for a panel in extjs

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1

I am dynamically adding panel to a container. i want to set a tool-tip for this panel on hover. how to do that?

```
var myPanel = Ext.create('myClass.extending panel');
myPanel.id = 'my-id';
myPanel.setTitle('myTitle');              
myPanel.collapsed = true;
this.add(myPanel);
```

**UPDATE:** I tried following also , but not working

```
var panelToolTip = Ext.create('Ext.tip.ToolTip', {
        target: 'my-id',
        html: 'I am a tooltip on your panel.'
});
this.add(panelToolTip);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved this by adding following code on panel extending class.

```
    listeners: {
    render: function () {
        this.getEl().dom.title = 'my custom tool tip';
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Jom Is there any way to increase size of this tool tip?

Answer (score 2):

The following snippet adds a tooltip to the specified id.

Edit: Here's my panel code, tested it with Firefox.

```
    var myPanel = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
     id : 'myPanel',
                    width: 200,
                    height: 150,
                    title: 'Panels are cool',
                    collapsible: true,
                    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
                    .. .some other properties
});
 var tip = Ext.create('Ext.tip.ToolTip', {
                target: 'myPanel',
                html: 'I am a tooltip on myPanel'
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use following way when you want to show two separate tool tip.

```
listeners: {
"collapse": function () {
    this.getEl().dom.title = 'collapse tooltip';
},
"expand": function () {
    this.getEl().dom.title = 'expand tooltip';
}
},
```